# How does Pointer increment in C for basic data types?

Tags: c

How does Pointer increment in C for basic data types?? 
  I am not able to understand why diff in following code is not giving me diffrence in bytes in memory location and it is givning me 1..

```
      Here is my code:: 
          char c1='c';
          char *c=&c1;
          int i1=1;
          int *i=&i1;
          long l1=1;
          long *l=&l1;
          float f1=1.1;
          float *f=&f1;
          double d1=1.3;
          double *d=&d1;
          printf("c =%u ,c +1=%u\n",c,c+1);
          printf("i =%u ,i +1=%u\n",i,i+1);
          printf("l =%u ,l +1=%u\n",l,l+1);
          printf("f =%u ,f +1=%u\n",f,f+1);
          printf("d =%u ,d +1=%u\n",d,d+1);

          printf("c diff =%u\n",(c+1)-(c));
          printf("i diff =%d\n",(i+1)-(i));
          printf("l diff =%u\n",(l+1)-(l));
          printf("f diff =%u\n",(f+1)-(f));
          printf("d diff =%u\n",(d+1)-(d));

          printf("c diff =%u\n",(c)-(c+1));
          printf("i diff =%u\n",(i)-(i+1));
          printf("l diff =%u\n",(l)-(l+1));
          printf("f diff =%u\n",(f)-(f+1));
          printf("d diff =%u\n",(d)-(d+1));

    Output::c =1636923 ,c +1=1636924
    i =1636896 ,i +1=1636900
    l =1636872 ,l +1=1636876
    f =1636848 ,f +1=1636852
    d =1636820 ,d +1=1636828
    c diff =1
    i diff =1
    l diff =1
    f diff =1
    d diff =1
    c diff =4294967295
    i diff =4294967295
    l diff =4294967295
    f diff =4294967295
    d diff =4294967295

    Why I am not getting "i diff =%d\n",(i+1)-(i) ==>> 4
```

Comment: It works as well for adding as subtracting.  If you want to see the difference in bytes then you'll have to cast the pointer to char*.

Comment: How does pointer increment work? If `p` is a pointer of type `T *` and points to an element within an array of `T`s, then `p + 1` points to the next element in the array, or possible one-past-the-end. (And you can treat a single element as an array of one.)

Comment: Pointer math is based on the underlying *type* of the pointer. It is not a "byte" count. Just as `Type *a;` and `++a` appropriately moves a by `sizeof(Type)` bytes , performing a pointer *difference* will perform similar logic, but result in `n` as a difference of `Type` sized objects; not bytes. And note, pointer differencing is only valid for *valid contiguous blocks* of storage with *no* holes.

Comment: The correct way to print a pointer value is to use a cast to convert it to `void*` and use the `"%p"` format. `printf("c =%p ,c +1=%p\n", (void*)c, (void*)(c+1));`

Comment: @user814064: The result of subtracting two pointers is of type `ptrdiff_t`, which is a *signed* type; neither `%u` nor `%x` is appropriate. Assuming `ptrdiff_t` is no wider than `unsigned long`, you can cast to `unsigned long` and print with `%ld`.

Comment: Any decent C tutorial should explain how pointer arithmetic works.

Comment: For statements such as `long l1 = 1;` and `float f1 = 1.1;` you might want to specify that the literals on the right hand side are `long` and `float` as follows: `long l1 = 1L;` `float f1 = 1.1F;`

Comment: @user2336676: Apparently you expected the binary `-` operator to give you pointer difference in bytes. It doesn't and it was never supposed to. So, take your favorite C book, read the chapter on pointer arithmetic to learn how it works. Making random assumptions (as this one about "difference in bytes") will not help you to achieve anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things here: When you're doing pointer arithmetic you aren't dealing with bytes, you're dealing with X*sizeof(pointertype). When you say (i+1)-i, you're not doing a "how many bytes" operation, you're instead getting back the number of pointer positions between the two points. It's the difference in pointer positions.

Answer (score 1):

Pointer arithmetic is *always* in units of the pointed-to type. Not only does this mean `p + 1` internally adds `sizeof(*p)` to the memory address (which is what you see in the first 4 lines), but also that `p - q` tells you how many *items* are between the two pointers, not how many *bytes* there are. The last four numbers are about 4 billion because the type used for these calculations is unsigned and hence underflows: `p+1` is larger than `p`, so `p - (p+1)` would be negative.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not able to understand why diff in following code is not giving me diffrence in bytes

Because it's not specified to do that.

> and it is givning me 1

If you add 1 to X and subtract away X, you get back 1. That's a law of arithmetic. C has "pointer arithmetic" and it obeys laws of arithmetic (if the operation in question is defined). No big surprise here.

Answer (score 1):

```
Why I am not getting "i diff =%d\n",(i+1)-(i) ==>> 4
```

Because its like this in most cases  :

```
(i+1) - (i) / sizeof(int)
```

which is equal to 1.

But you should note that this is not defined , as quoted in the C standard ,for  pointer subtraction to work both the pointer should point to the elements in the same array or just beyond it :

**From C11 standard (6.5.6 para #9)**

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the
>   same array object, or one past the last element of the array object;
>   the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array
>   elements.